# JavaScript filter array based on user roles

Tags: javascript

I want to filter the array based on the user roles fetching from server. Below is the sample JSON response getting from server,

```js
var mainObj =

      [{
          "title": "Merchant",
          "role": ["0"],
          "subMenu": [{
            "subMenu1": "Initiate",
            "role": ["1"]
          }]
        },
        {
          "title": "Prepaid",
          "role": ["1"],
          "subMenu": [{
              "subMenu1": "Merch1",
              "role": ["2"]
            },
            {
              "subMenu1": "Merch3",
              "role": ["1"]
            }

          ]
        }
      ]
```

And Filter the array based on the userFlag,

```js
    var userRole = {"userFlag": 1};
```

I have tried to apply filter in the below but not applying correctly. can any one help on this.

```js
var mainObj =

  [{
      "title": "Merchant",
      "role": ["0"],
      "subMenu": [{
        "subMenu1": "Initiate",
        "role": ["1"]
      }]
    },
    {
      "title": "Prepaid",
      "role": ["1"],
      "subMenu": [{
          "subMenu1": "Merch1",
          "role": ["2"]
        },
        {
          "subMenu1": "Merch3",
          "role": ["1"]
        }

      ]
    }
  ]

const result = mainObj.filter(role => role.find(group => userRole.userFlag.includes(group.role)))
```

Expected output,

```json
[
   {
      "title":"Prepaid",
      "role":[
         "1"
      ],
      "subMenu":[
         {
            "subMenu1":"Merch3",
            "role":[
               "1"
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Comment: Can you post the sample output you have in mind

Comment: @chyke007: I have added expected output. Can you please help on this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this out

```js
var mainObj =
  
  [
    {
      "title": "Merchant",
      "role":["0"],
      "subMenu": [
        {
          "subMenu1": "Initiate",
          "role": ["1"]
        },
      ]
    },
    {
      "title": "Prepaid",
      "role":["1"],
      "subMenu": [
        {
          "subMenu1": "Merch1",
          "role": ["2"]
        },
        {
          "subMenu1": "Merch3",
          "role": ["1"]
        },

      ]
    }
    ]

    const userRole = {"userFlag": 1};
    const key = `${userRole.userFlag}`;

    function filterInner(ob){
        const res = ob.subMenu.filter(object => object.role.includes(key))
        return {...ob, subMenu: res}
    }


const returnVal = []
const result = mainObj.map(object => {
const innerfilter = filterInner(object)
      innerfilter.role.includes(key) ? returnVal.push({...object, subMenu: innerfilter.subMenu}) : null
});


console.log(returnVal)
```

Comment: Great!  its working as expected. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Given

1. `mainObj` contains objects whose `role` value is an array of strings like `["0", "1"]`
2. `userRole` contains a single key `userFlag` whose value is a single int, like `1`
3. an object is matched when the `userRole` (in string form) is present in its `role` array

then the predicate is:

```
const userFlagStr = `${userRole.userFlag}`;
const result = mainObj.filter(object => object.role.includes(userFlagStr))
```

**edit** OP clarified the question to match any role in the object.

Let's build some machinery to handle this...

```js
// return an array of roles inside the object, including the subMenu roles
const rolesIn = object => {
  const subRoles = object.subMenu.map(o => o.role).flat()
  return [...object.role, ...subRoles]
}

var mainObj = [{
    "title": "This one has no 1",
    "role": ["999"],
    "subMenu": [{
      "subMenu1": "Initiate",
      "role": ["999"]
    }]
  },
  {
    "title": "Merchant",
    "role": ["0"],
    "subMenu": [{
      "subMenu1": "Initiate",
      "role": ["1"]
    }]
  },
  {
    "title": "Prepaid",
    "role": ["1"],
    "subMenu": [{
        "subMenu1": "Merch1",
        "role": ["2"]
      },
      {
        "subMenu1": "Merch3",
        "role": ["1"]
      }

    ]
  }
]


const userRole = {
  userFlag: 1
}
const userFlagStr = `${userRole.userFlag}`;
const result = mainObj.filter(object => rolesIn(object).includes(userFlagStr))
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but its only filtering the parent object not the child. I have added the sample output. can you please help on this

Comment: @vishnu - edited.  the new idea is to collect roles from the objects into an array by mapping the subMenu and combining with the top level role, then check inclusion in that larger array

Comment: Filter not applying, it showing complete array instead of actual output. Can you please help this?

Comment: @vishnu - It works according to my understanding of the problem. In the test input, both objects contain role "1", and it finds both. Objects that don't contain 1 get filtered.

Comment: `@danh` -  I am looking for the exact solution which `chyke007` has shared. Thanks!